# Unexpected result when calling the same web service multiple times simultaneously

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

I am having a problem when issuing many requests to the same web service operation simultaneously (that is, in many threads).

Each time I call the web service, I log it to the console, so my output is something like

```
Calling OperationA with paramA = 'A'
Calling OperationA with paramA = 'B'
Calling OperationA with paramA = 'C'
Calling OperationA with paramA = 'D'
...
Calling OperationA with paramA = 'Z'
```

which shows that I'm calling the same operation with different parameters.

I'm using Fiddler to trace these requests, and I expected to see all of my requests in the order they were issued on the application. But it's all wrong: the requests are all out of order, some requests are issued more than once, and some are not issued at all (that is, my printf says I called it, but Fiddler doesn't show anything).

It seems like the problem is issuing a lot of requests in a short period of time, because if I put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` between each call, everything works like a charm.

Is this some kind of expected behavior? Why aren't the requests being queued correctly?

By the way, this is a C# 2.0 client, invoking an AXIS 2.0 secure web service using a proxy class generated by wsdl.exe, and I'm using the asynchronous "begin*Operation*" and "end*Operation*" methods in the proxy class to issue the requests.

EDIT: Here's how I'm calling this operation over and over:

```
foreach(List listOfMyClass1 in  listOfListOfMyClass1)
{
 MyClass2[] webServiceParameter = listOfMyClass1.ToArray();

 // Here I log that I'm calling the operation, and print every element in webServiceParameter

 IAsyncResult ar = wsClient.BeginOperationA(webServiceParameter);

 listOfAsyncResults.Add(ar);

  // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); --> This solves the problem..
}

foreach(IAsyncResult ar in listOfAsyncResults)
{
 WebServiceResultClass result = wsClient.EndOperationA(ar);
}
```

Comment: Hm. Are you seeing only two simultaneous requests at any given time? Could it be the http-limit of 2 connections per remote server that messes things up?

Comment: I didn't know there was such a limit... How does that work? But it looks like sometimes there are many (more than 2) requests being served (by looking at Fiddler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that old problem of changing a variable that was declared outside the loop on each iteration, and using it inside the loop. I mean, it was somewhat similar to this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
IList<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
for(int i = 0; i < someInt; i++)
{
    c.SomeProperty = i;
    myClassList.Add(c);
}
// And here every "SomeProperty" is the same for every element in the list, since every element references the same variable.
```

More specifically, the `webServiceParameter` array (see the code in the question) is actually assigned to a property of another variable (which was declared outside the loop), and this variable is passed to the service call.

So, when too many calls were made very fast, by the time these calls got dispatched, the array would contain the values from the last iteration, causing the 'repeated requests'.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect them to go in any particular order, but each should only occur once.

I'm going to use psychic debugging to try to work out what's wrong though... I suspect you've got a loop like this:

```
foreach (string input in data)
{
    new Thread(() => CallWebService(input)).Start();
}
```

This is capturing the loop variable - which is a [bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). It's easy to fix though:

```
foreach (string input in data)
{
    string copy = input;
    new Thread(() => CallWebService(copy)).Start();
}
```

(The previous link will explain what's going on... and [here's the second part](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).)

If that *isn't* the case, please give us some code - otherwise we're really just guessing.

Comment: I tested it, and this doesn't seem to be the problem.. I edited my question and put a simplified version of my code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect them to go in any particular order? What part of the system controls this? I had imagined that, when calling a beginOperation method, .NET would start a new thread ('immediately') and dispatch this request right away, causing the requests to be issued in the same order that the loop variable is iterated over.

Comment: @dsetton: There's a per-host connection limit. I'd expect that when the connections are all in-flight, with several threads queuing requests, the order in which those requests were processed may not be determinate. I certainly wouldn't want to rely on it.

Comment: @dsetton: Okay, so your sample *looks* okay. Any chance you could put it into a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ok.. but how? I mean, what else should I put there? The problem is that if `listOfListOfMyClass1` has many elements, this loop issues many requests very fast, and then I see all that mess I described. I could put here the Fiddler session with the requests.. and then you would be able to compare that with that printf output.. would that help?

Comment: The problem was so simple after all (see my answer above). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dsetton: That's where a short but complete program is important, of course :) Glad you sorted it though.